# How to parse HTTP request with a missing content type in Express/ NodeJs, by assuming a default content type?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, http-headers

How can I get access to the POST data in a request, if the express `bodyParser` does not fire?

```
var server = express();
server.use(express.bodyParser());
server.post('/api/v1', function(req, resp) {
  var body = req.body;
  //if request header does not contain 'Content-Type: application/json'
  //express bodyParser does not parse the body body is undefined
  var out = {
    'echo': body
  };
  resp.contentType('application/json');
  resp.send(200, JSON.stringify(out));
});
```

Note: in ExpressJs 3.x+ `req.body` is not automatically available, and requires `bodyParser` to activate.

If a content type header is not set, is it possible to specify a default content type of `application/json` and trigger the `bodyParser`?

Otherwise is it possible to access the POST data using the bare nodejs way from within this express POST function?

(e.g. `req.on('data', function...`)

Comment: just use `req.on('data')` or do `req.headers['content-type'] = req.headers['content-type'] || 'application/json'` before the body parser, but really this is a client error.

Comment: @JonathanOng thanks. Yes, I know that this is a client error - just trying to work around it. How would I go about doing something before the body parser kicks in? AFAICT, it has already been triggered by the time this express PUT callback function is entered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a bunch of options including manually invoking the express (connect, really) middleware functions yourself (really, go read the source code. They are just functions and there is no deep magic to confuse you). So:

```
function defaultContentTypeMiddleware (req, res, next) {
  req.headers['content-type'] = req.headers['content-type'] || 'application/json';
  next();
}

app.use(defaultContentTypeMiddleware);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - just checking that since we are using content type as a hash directly, whether capitalisation will affect this? i.e. `req.headers['content-type']` vs `req.headers['Content-Type']`?

Comment: They are lowercased for you. http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_message_headers

Comment: @ Peter Lyons Unforunately, setting the header properties this way appeared to have no effect on the `bodyParser`. Thanks for giving me the idea of writing my own middleware though - don't know why it didn't occur to me to do so myself - but ultimately what I wound up doing was to write my own middleware, which was essentially a minimal wrapper around `req.on('data', function...` and `JSON.parse`. +1 and check to you!

Answer (score 4):

I use this middleware, before bodyParser kicks in, which may help.
It peeks at the first byte of the request stream, and makes a guess.
This particular app only really handles XML or JSON text streams.

```
app.use((req,res, next)=>{
    if (!/^POST|PUT$/.test(req.method) || req.headers['content-type']){
        return next();
    }
    if ((!req.headers['content-length'] || req.headers['content-length'] === '0') 
            && !req.headers['transfer-encoding']){
        return next();
    }
    req.on('readable', ()=>{
        //pull one byte off the request stream
        var ck = req.read(1);
        var s = ck.toString('ascii');
        //check it
        if (s === '{' || s==='['){req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';}
        if (s === '<'){req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/xml'; }
        //put it back at the start of the request stream for subsequent parse
        req.unshift(ck);
        next();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In Express 4.x, had the same problem, whe client was misbehaved and did not send the content type. Passing some configs to express.json() did the trick:

```
app.use(express.json({inflate: true, strict: false, type: () => { return true; } }));
```