# Getting error - 11200 in twilio in programmable voice

Tags: twilio

I am having an intermittent issue with Twilio. Once out of every 50 calls, we get a call that fails, and when I check the logs, it states that it is error 11200, and it gives "An attempt to retrieve content from https://mednection.azurewebsites.net/appointment/fallback returned the HTTP status code 500"

I've taken a look at Twilio's suggestions regarding this error (found at https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/11200). They list a bunch of probable causes for a bad gateway error:

1) Web server returned a 4xx or 5xx HTTP response to Twilio - as far as I can see in the logs, the web server is returning a 200 HTTP response to Twilio. 2) Misconfigured Web Server - We have checked the configuration of our web server, and believe it to be correct. 3) Network disruptions between Twilio and your web server - we have tested the ping response time, and the packet loss between www.twilio.com and our server. The ping time is < 15 sec, and there seems to be no packet loss when testing with ping -n 100 www.twilio.com 4) No Content-Type header attached to response - we set our Content-Type to application/xml. 5) Content-Type doesn't match actual content - We set our Content-Type to application/xml and are using the TwiML language to send our responses back.

We have also checked all elements in Twilio's Possible Solutions section for this error.

A bit about what we are doing:

We are working on appointment creation system. In this two call goes simultaneously to check availability of both parties, while hangup the call i got this issue.

I'm not ruling out that it's something at our end that is causing the issue, but we don't really know what to check next. The web server appears to be sending a 200 response back, but Twilio seems to be receiving a 502.

Does anybody have any suggestions that might help us out? Could it be a problem with the API we are using?

Thank you in advance!

twilio

Comment: 1) wich langage and framework are you using ? 2) maybe a forgotten debug string sent before a http header ? 3) maybe your server or framework has a request limit for the same ip per minute? 4) It's always each 50 request, or approximately ?

Comment: If Twilio received a 500 error from your application, then it is likely on your end. Do you have error tracking and reporting in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio seems to forget to set `content-type` for their requests... Which makes it impossible for a middleware to parse the body.

If you are using Node.js with express, here is a solution:

- Check if there is no `content-type` set
- If not, assume it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which seems to be the actual content type Twilio is sending.

```js
// This is used by your TwiML App as the Voice Request Url
app.post('/makecall', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.headers['content-type']) {
    req.headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    const urlEncodedMiddleware = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
    urlEncodedMiddleware(req, res, next)
  } else {
    next()
  }
}, makeCall);
```

This solution is a bit future proof if Twilio decides to start sending `content-type`. But, it could break if they change the body format without sending the `content-type`...

Solution inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17228529/1340601