# Is there a way to take values out of this request body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, httprequest

I am using node.js and express to receive post requests from another service that I do not manage. The request body returns in the console as follows.

```
{
  '{"org_id":"TSTORG","network_id":0,"ts":"2021-09-01T17:40:24","device_name":"Test Device","device_id":0,"ssid":"Test SSID","client_name":"Test Client Device","client_mac":"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF","event_type":"WLAN","detail":"Event log notification test","longitude":0.1,"latitude":0.2,"gps_timestamp":"2021-09-01T17:40:24","sn":"0000-0000-0000"}': ''
}
```

It seems to be a JSON Object with a JSON string inside of it. Is this request malformed or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Step 1 feels like it should be "read the documentation for that service to understand what it's sending you"? Unless you say which service it is, and based on what triggers you're getting this POST, no one will be able to tell you whether this is the expected POST payload or not (in fact, the most qualified person to tell us whether it is or not, is you =)

Comment: That's the result of not having a JSON Bodyparser attached as middleware.

Comment: Body parser is attached. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Wheelzaboo then the middleware isn't being reached, either because the request doesn't have a proper content type, or the middleware is placed after the route.

Comment: For the frst issue, if you can't fix it outside of your server and your server must handle this request without a proper content type, [the middleware shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227881/how-to-parse-http-request-with-a-missing-content-type-in-express-nodejs-by-ass) will help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually figured this out.

```
var data = request.body;
var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
```

I had to use the Object.keys method to return just the text inside the object. From there:

```
var p = JSON.parse(key)
console.log(p)
```

This allowed me to reform the JSON string I got back into a workable JSON format that I could extract values from.